# How can I use the Vue.js code from a webpack bundle in a Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, vue.js

Here is my Razor page code:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;

@{ BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
       new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Vuejs")
            .Include("~/Static/Scripts/Vuejs/vue.min.js")); }

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Static/vue/assets/bundle.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Vuejs")
}

<div id="app_container">
    {{text}}
</div>
```

and here is the entry of the webpack javascript:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app_container',
    data: { text: 'abcdefg' }
});
```

Webpack config:

```
export default {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/index.js'
    ],

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: 'C:/WebSandbox/Static/vue/assets',
        publicPath: '/vue/assets/'
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' },
            { test: /\.js/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
            { test: /\.txt/, loader: 'raw' }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                APP_ENV: JSON.stringify('browser')
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

All the javascript files are in place and when open the page I can see the mapped code from Developer Tools of Chrome. And if I make a break point in the javascript code, it will be hit.
But the text displayed is "{{text}}", not "abcdefg".

If I added following code after the `div`:

```
<script>
    const v = new Vue({ el: "#app_container", data: { text: "abcdefg" } });
</script>
```

or add following code and remove the javascript file from @section Scripts part

```
<script src='~/Static/vue/assets/bundle.js'></script>
```

It works.

So how can I make my webpack bundle work with the @Scripts.Render in Razor page?

Comment: If adding the script tag fixes this, then the webpack part is working. Your issue may be in the rendering of the script sections. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325027/asp-net-mvc-4-add-bundle-from-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now I found why the bundle not working:

Because the @RenderSection("Scripts", false) was written in the header of _Layout.cshtml. So the bundle JavaScript file will be referenced in the header. But when I switch to the raw reference (script tag), it will be after my div tag where it should be.
When I change the bundle part to:

```
@section ScriptBlock {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Static/vue/assets/bundle.js")
}
```

It works.

The @RenderSection("ScriptBlock", false) was written in the bottom of the _Layout.cshtml right after the closing tag of body.

Answer (score 0):

I use vuejs with asp.net with browserify rather than webpack. 
And the packing should be an independent build step. 
I setup a gulp task to take my vue code and bundle it up and place it in the scripts folder of asp.net.

I think you need to do something similar here.